# Using Serializable as deep link argument with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

Is it possible to use a custom `Serializable` object as a fragment argument when using deep links?

I've tried the following - in my navigation graph XML file I've added following lines:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/eventFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.EventFragment"
    android:label="EventFragment">

    <argument
        android:name="event"
        app:argType="com.myapp.EventId" />

    <deepLink app:uri="myapp://event/{event}" />

</fragment>
```

Where `EventId` is a serializable data class:

```
data class EventId(val value: Long) : Serializable
```

Then, when I'm trying to run my application with an URL `myapp://event/4002`, the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serializables don't support default values.
        at androidx.navigation.NavType$SerializableType.parseValue(NavType.java:834)
        at androidx.navigation.NavType$SerializableType.parseValue(NavType.java:787)
        at androidx.navigation.NavType.parseAndPut(NavType.java:96)
        at androidx.navigation.NavDeepLink.getMatchingArguments(NavDeepLink.java:99)
        at androidx.navigation.NavDestination.matchDeepLink(NavDestination.java:366)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraph.matchDeepLink(NavGraph.java:79)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.handleDeepLink(NavController.java:540)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:499)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:460)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:425)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:407)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:236)
```

Replacing type with `long` (`app:argType="long"`) solves the issue - there is no exception and everything works as expected.

It seems like the navigation library does not know how to convert the raw value from the URL to my `EventId` class. Is it possible to somehow register an adapter which knows how to convert it? Or maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you only have one other alternative to what you have done: [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).

I think it will be sufficient in this case, but I am not sure, but even if it doesn't, this will be a good recommendation for any future Android development when you for example need to send data between Activities or fragments.

Especially as I can see you are using Kotlin, which has a helper method for implementing it correctly, see: [Parcelize](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable-implementations-generator).

With it, your data class would simply look like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class EventId(val value: Long) : Parcelable
```

Side note:
Usage of the Serializable interface is discouraged for various reasons. From the book [Effective Java](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java-3rd/9780134686097/ch12.xhtml) written by [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) who worked on Java for a long time:

```
Item 85: Prefer alternatives to Java serialization
```

If you still have to use Serializable, the book will cover the necessary details.

Comment: Unfortunately, even Parcelables are not supported. Check out this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975553/parcelables-dont-support-default-values-android-navigation-deeplink-argument

Comment: It is not questions answer.